# Seeking birth/baptism record for Salamina Radke from Kulm, Russia?

Tags: united-states, birth-records, immigration, russia, baptism-records

I am researching the ancestors of Salamina Radke from Kulm, Russia.

She was born August 19, 1876 and immigrated to the United States.

How can I find her birth/baptism record to identify her parents?

Comment: Hi, Karen, welcome to G&FH.SE! Questions that ask for "any information" or "any ancestors" are very broad and won't attract good answers. Please see our guidelines on [What topics can I ask about here?](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [How Do I Ask a Good Question?](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).  If you show us what research you've already done, we can give you better advice.

Comment: To try and make your question better fit our focussed Q&A format I am going to edit it.  Please do not be offended that I am doing this but it should prevent it from being closed as too broad.  This site works quite differently to a bulletin board or discussion forum.  If I have not made it ask the question that you are most looking to have answered then you can easily [edit] it to make it do so, or [ask another question](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Comment: Please summarize what records you have already searched. Salamina's obit is attached to her Findagrave entry [http://www.findagrave.com/cgi-bin/fg.cgi?page=gr&GRid=65565527 ]. It names 2 half-sisters among her survivors -- have you researched them? Kulm is in Bessarabia -- have you researched the resources for that region and the Germans who lived there? She came to the USA at 2yrs - did she come with her parents?